# EF code first: what is the correct way to initialize DB?

Tags: entity-framework

In my project I using Entity Framework 6 and Code First approach. My goal is to initialize database with all the required initial data. Based on research I did, I decided to implement IDatabaseInitializer. However, there is something that I can't understand, and I will glad to get some explanation.

I want to use "dropcreatedatabaseifmodelchanges" strategy. However, one single initializer works against one single context. In my project, I have several contexts. So, I decided to create several initializers, one per context.

But there is a problem: first initializer loads, drops DB and adds its data. After that second initializer loads and drops DB (together with data from previous initializer)... So, I end with DB loaded with data only from last initializer.

Obviously, my approach is wrong. What the correct way to initialize DB, in case there is more than one DB context?

Thanks

Comment: I can understand having several models for a single database, but re-creating the database based on only one of those models then becomes just plain impossible. Either use a single unified model, or don't let EF create the database for you, I don't think there are any other options.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create one context which holds all entity sets of all contexts and initialize database from that context. Then you can create and use smaller contexts.